# Python image to string converting none of modules works

Tags: python, image, ocr, pytesser

I am using module like pytesseract, textract, pyocr, all with Image modul. After opening .jpg file I can display the file but I just can't read the text from the file. I use three kinds of modules nad all th etime I had the same error: The system cannot find the file specified. I use Python 3.5.

The error is in config of this part of code in pytesseract in config=config) # here is a problem.

Do you have any ideas?
I' ve search the internet, I've found some examples like lang='eng'and nothing still works.

Code example with pytesseract module is very simple:

```
im = Image.open("C:/Temp/Example.jpg")
im.show() # it works
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(im)
print(text)
```

I also used some attributes and nothing works...

Please let me know if sb knows what is going on.

Comment: try this pyocr.get_available_tools() and check if tesseract is installed properly

Comment: When I print it, i get only empty list. So when I want to use e.g get_available_languages() I get also nothing...

Comment: Add `import pytesseract` and `from PIL import Image` at the beginning. Assuming you installed pytesseract properly it should work.

Comment: Of course I've got these two imports above. Nothing works, the axact mistake is: FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: Either your `pytesseract` installation is not good or you are not defining the correct path to your image, though I don't think it's the latter since you say the image opens.

Comment: I am running into a similar problem and after some searching noticed others complaining about the installation of `pytesseract`. `pip freeze` shows I have the `pytesseract` version 0.2.0 module installed but when I run the python code I recieve an ImportError: No module named 'pytesseract'.

Comment: I am sure that the path is correct because the picture opens. I als orestaretd my computer and still nothing works. Maybe I'll try another one pytesseract instalation... I've got 0.1.8 version pytesseract.

Comment: I guess you only have the tesseract python wrapper and not the tesseract backend. Install from here https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki

Comment: Probably you may be right. But I have no admin rights, is it possible to install it another way? Is this source code the same https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/releases ?